# Polymorphic Command Parser Design

Tags: c++

Would love some opinions on this problem I'm trying to workout.  I'm trying to improve my OO experience and fully leverage C++'s polymorphic capabilities.  I'm trying to write some code for a basic command parser.  They command structure goes as so:

[command name] [arguments]

The command name will just be limited to a one word string. The arguments can be a 0 to N list of strings.

Each command and list of arguments could be directed to any variety of software objects in my system.  So for example I could have an rtp statistics command map to my rtp module,  the user statistics to my user module.  Something like that.

Right now the entry point for my CLI provides the entire command string as a standard string.  And it provides a standard output stream for displaying results to the user.

I really want to avoid using a parser function and then doing an if then else kind of deal.  So I was thinking something like this:

1. I would have a base class called command.  Its constructor would take the string command, the stdout, and an interface for the object it needs to interact with.
2. I would create a command factory that would match the command name to the object that handles it.  This would instantiate the right command object for the right command.
3. Each separate command object would parse the given arguments and make the right choices for this command.

What I'm struggling with is how to give the right module to the right command.  Is this where I should use a template argument?  So that each command can take any interface and I'll let the factory decide which module to pass in to the command object?

I'm also open to other opinions as well.  I'm just trying to learn and hoping the community can give me some tips :-).

Comment: I understand the desire to not want to use an "if then else kind of deal", but you should realize that your factory implementation will almost certainly have to do this.  There is no way to (at compile time) generate specific code paths that are only known at run time.

Comment: Well I understand that at the very base you need that statement.  However I wanted to avoid using a complex hierarchy of if/else structures.  I'd rather just use it to instantiate the right object and then let that object do that job.

Comment: In which case, the factory method will suit your needs nicely, and I'd point you to @Rafael_Baptista 's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is a common pattern in OOP.  [*Design Patterns*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)  (the Gang of Four book) referred to this as a [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

There's generally no need for templates.  Everything is parsed and dispatched at runtime, so dynamic polymorphism (virtual functions) is probably a better choice.

In another answer, Rafael Baptista suggested a basic design.  Here is how I would modify his design to be more complete:

### Command objects and CommandDispatcher

Commands are handled by subclasses of the `Command` class.  Commands are dispatched by a `CommandDispatcher` object that handles the basic parsing of the command string (basically, splitting at spaces, possibly handling quoted strings, etc.).

The system registers an instance of `Command` with the `CommandDispatcher`, and associates each instance of `Command` with a command name (`std::string`).  The association is handled by a `std::map` object, although that could be replaced by a hash table (or similar structure to associate key-value pairs).

```
class Command
{
  public:
    virtual ~Command(void);
    virtual void execute(FILE* in, const std::vector<std::string>& args) = 0;
};

class CommandDispatcher
{
  public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, Command*> CommandMap;

    void registerCommand(const std::string& commandName, Command* command)
    {
      CommandMap::const_iterator cmdPair = registeredCommands.find(commandName);
      if (cmdPair != registeredCommands.end())
      {
        // handle error: command already registered
      }
      else
      {
        registeredCommands[commandName] = command;
      }
    }

    // possibly include isRegistered, unregisterCommand, etc.

    void run(FILE* in, const std::string& unparsedCommandLine); // parse arguments, call command
    void dispatch(FILE* in, const std::vector<std::string>& args)
    {
      if (! args.empty())
      {
        CommandMap::const_iterator cmdPair = registeredCommands.find(args[0]);
        if (cmdPair == registeredCommands.end())
        {
          // handle error: command not found
        }
        else
        {
          Command* cmd = cmdPair->second;
          cmd->execute(in, args);
        }
      }
    }


  private:
    CommandMap registeredCommands;
};
```

I've left the parsing, and other details out, but this is a pretty common structure for command patterns.  Notice how the `std::map` handles associating the command name with the command object.

### Registering commands

To make use of this design, you need to register commands in the system.  You need to instantiate `CommandDispatcher`, either using a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern, in `main`, or in another central location.

Then, you need to register the command objects.  There are several ways to do this.  The way I prefer, because you have more control, is to have each module (set of related commands) provide its own registration function.  For example, if you have a 'File IO' module, then you might have a function `fileio_register_commands`:

```
void fileio_register_commands(CommandDispatcher* dispatcher)
{
  dispatcher->registerCommand( "readfile", new ReadFileCommand );
  dispatcher->registerCommand( "writefile", new WriteFileCommand );
  // etc.
}
```

Here `ReadFileCommand` and `WriteFileCommand` are subclasses of `Command` that implement the desired behavior.

You have to make sure to call `fileio_register_commands` before the commands become available.

This approach can be made to work for dynamically loaded libraries (DLLs or shared libraries).  Make sure that the function to register commands has a regular pattern, based on the name of the module: `XXX_register_commands`, where `XXX` is, for example, the lower cased module name.  After you load the shared library or DLL, your code can determine whether such a function exists, and then call it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation.  This makes perfect sense.  So each module will register the commands appropriate to it.  And that will form the link between the command and the module.  I will grab a copy of "Design Patterns" as well ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Templates is overkill. I imagine you want something where the command interpreter just figures out what commands are possible from the objects that are available.

For each class that wants to support this CLI, I'd give it a function that registers the class, and the command name that triggers that class.

```
class CLIObject
{
   virtual void registerCli( Cli& cli ) = 0;
   virtual bool doCommand( FILE* file, char** args ) = 0;
}

class HelloWorld : public ClIObject 
{
   void registerCli( Cli& cli ) { cli.register( this, "helloworld" ); }
   bool doCommand( FILE* file, char** args ) 
   { 
       if ( !args[0] ) return false;     
       fprintf( file, "hello world! %s", args[0] ); 
       return true; 
   }
}
```

Now your cli can support any class that derives from CLIObject.

Comment: Yeah this looks much better.  However I'm still a little confused.  How will I make sure that each CLIObject has a pointer to the module it needs to interact with?  If I were operating on just one object I could pass in an interface API to each "doCommand".  But if there are many modules, how can I make sure that these CLIObjects get the right module?